# What is this HTML technique

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have recently started to see websites with full size, full width background images, and when you scroll down there comes a section with some content and then a different background. and that scrolls with the page. I am sure if you have seen it you know what I am talking about.

How do you call this technique? Is there a name for it? I would like to look for a tutorial on this, but I don't know what to look for.

Thanks!

Comment: Try Parallax and enjoy!

Comment: That's it! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u are looking for [Parallax Scrolling Website](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/parallax-scrolling-1131762).

There are many tutorials for doing that easily.

A simple example for that is given **[here](https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)**.

Moe can be found-

1. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/web-design-inspiration-scrollin-scrollin-scrollin--cms-25486
2. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-give-your-logo-the-slip-scroll-effect--cms-22274
3. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-masked-background-effect-with-css--cms-21112
4. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/building-a-complete-website-with-the-gumby-framework--webdesign-16980
5. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/working-with-gumbys-parallax-extension--webdesign-16967
6. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/jazz-up-a-static-webpage-with-subtle-parallax--webdesign-10195
7. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellarjs--webdesign-7307
8. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641

If u like to implement Parallax with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), then this tutorial is for u-

> https://www.impulse-themes.com/zenith/development/twitter-bootstrap-parallax-scrolling

Think u have your complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps looking for [Parallax](http://cyberchimps.com/parallax-web-design/)? There are many resources online with instructions about it, hopefully knowing the term will get you there.

Here's a simple [demo](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/) with pure CSS Parallax, but you could also [check out Awwwards for some inspiration.](http://www.awwwards.com/websites/parallax/)

Answer (score 1):

> The term “parallax” first came from the visual effect of 2D side scrolling videogames that used different background image movement speeds to create the illusion of depth during gameplay. This was generally done by making the background of the game move slower than the foreground in order to make it seem further away. This same concept applies to parallax site design in which the background of the website moves at a different speed as the rest of the page for an impressive visual effect that allows for countless creative applications for online storytelling.

You can check the link below for more information, tips and some downsides as well.

[See More](https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2013/08/15/what-parallax-web-design-%E2%80%93-definitions-tips-considerations)